# How to Assign sequential IP Address to multiple hosted .net core api's on Windows Docker Containers on same windows machine

Tags: docker

I have deployed multiple instances of .net core web api on windows docker container but the default IP Address assignment is not sequential(ex. 172.17.43.100,172.17.44.100) while if I am hosting instances of linux container the IP address assignment are sequential(example 172.17.0.2,172.17.0.3), I need to achieve the same in windows docker container, so that I can scan the IP address in that subnet sequentially.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about your use case?  Why are you trying to scan IP addresses, and how?  Why do the container-internal IP addresses matter?

Comment: I have to create a mock device instances on my machine to test and develop UI, for its configuration. In actual every devices have server and some services hosted on it, to configure each of them. These devices are connected to internal network, each device have assigned IP in a sequence. In order to reduce device scan overhead these ip were assigned as sequential would be better. I am able to achieve the same with Linux container but need to know the same with windows container.